# Eigen 3.3.4 Fedora 27 memory alignment fail often

Tags: eigen, memory-alignment, eigen3

Eigen 3.3.4 memory alignment fails on my programs but used to work before.
Especially some structure creates invalid free and redirect me to [this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__Alignement.html) even though the class itself already has the macro `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW`.

This has happened repetitively on multiple projects.

For example here is the Valgrind log after a crash:

```
==7191== Thread 1:
==7191== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==7191==    at 0x4C30D18: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==7191==    by 0x785419: perception_oru::NDTMap::NDTMap(perception_oru::SpatialIndex*, float, float, float, float, float, float, bool) (ndt_map.h:166)
==7191==    by 0x54A11B8: perception_oru::libgraphMap::NDTMapType::NDTMapType(boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam>) (ndt_map_type.cpp:14)
==7191==    by 0x54CC105: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphFactory::CreateMapType(boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam>) (graphfactory.cpp:53)
==7191==    by 0x54172E3: perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapNode::MapNode(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&) (map_node.cpp:44)
==7191==    by 0x54CC6C7: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphFactory::CreateMapNode(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&) (graphfactory.cpp:99)
==7191==    by 0x53D1D3F: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphMap::GraphMap(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphParam>) (graph_map.cpp:10)
==7191==    by 0x53E4DD4: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphMapNavigator::GraphMapNavigator(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphParam>) (graph_map_navigator.cpp:6)
==7191==    by 0x54CC534: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphFactory::CreateGraphNavigator(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam>&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphParam>) (graphfactory.cpp:85)
==7191==    by 0x541E6AA: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphMapFuser::GraphMapFuser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&) (graph_map_fuser.cpp:16)
==7191==    by 0x78D046: GraphMapFuserNode::GraphMapFuserNode(ros::NodeHandle) (graph_map_publisher_localization.cpp:377)
==7191==    by 0x77F016: main (graph_map_publisher_localization.cpp:1267)
==7191==  Address 0x41e78a40 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 512 alloc'd
==7191==    at 0x4C2FB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==7191==    by 0x781175: Eigen::internal::handmade_aligned_malloc(unsigned long) (Memory.h:88)
==7191==    by 0x7811F9: Eigen::internal::aligned_malloc(unsigned long) (Memory.h:164)
==7191==    by 0x796223: void* Eigen::internal::conditional_aligned_malloc<true>(unsigned long) (Memory.h:214)
==7191==    by 0x784F25: perception_oru::NDTCell::operator new(unsigned long) (ndt_cell.h:518)
==7191==    by 0x7853C6: perception_oru::NDTMap::NDTMap(perception_oru::SpatialIndex*, float, float, float, float, float, float, bool) (ndt_map.h:164)
==7191==    by 0x54A11B8: perception_oru::libgraphMap::NDTMapType::NDTMapType(boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam>) (ndt_map_type.cpp:14)
==7191==    by 0x54CC105: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphFactory::CreateMapType(boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam>) (graphfactory.cpp:53)
==7191==    by 0x54172E3: perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapNode::MapNode(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&) (map_node.cpp:44)
==7191==    by 0x54CC6C7: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphFactory::CreateMapNode(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&) (graphfactory.cpp:99)
==7191==    by 0x53D1D3F: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphMap::GraphMap(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphParam>) (graph_map.cpp:10)
==7191==    by 0x53E4DD4: perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphMapNavigator::GraphMapNavigator(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2, 0> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::MapParam> const&, boost::shared_ptr<perception_oru::libgraphMap::GraphParam>) (graph_map_navigator.cpp:6)
==7191==
```

And the code where the crash is reported read has:

```
NDTCell *ptCell = new NDTCell();
index_->setCellType(ptCell);
delete ptCell;
```

While that NDTCell class has Fixed size Eigen members, it also has `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` in the public part of its code. Now that's a long shot but also, the class containing the Class where the crash occurs is created like this :

```
boost::shared_ptr<MapType>(new NDTMapType(ndt2MapParam));
```

I don't understand why this code that used to work now crashes and I'm at a loss of idea as to why is Eigen not working with my code and what I do wrong.

Comment: What about compiling with `-DEIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED=0`? If that work then this means your system malloc is not aligned as expected.

Comment: The person who is developping the project I'm using told me to update to its latest version so I'm trying that first and then I'll try your suggestion :)

Comment: `Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()` sounds more like a double-`delete` operation. What is the type of `index_`? Does `setCellType` take ownership of the pointer?

Comment: Can't help you if you don't answer comments. You need to provide an actual [mcve] (with all includes and declarations to compile).

Comment: Yep sorry life just been really busy and I haven't had time to look up the answer to the question you've asked :/

Comment: Ok, I think the error came from a bunch of EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW still missing and the mixing of DEBUG and RELEASE libraries :/

Comment: I've been hit by this again in DEBUG mode and `-DEIGEN_MALLOC_ALREADY_ALIGNED=0` didn't help :/. Any other hint @ggael ? 
The double free arrive somewhere the pointer is created and deleted directly after